# how to find keywords in a multiline text?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a app that receives news from some news portals, I want to find the keywords of this news and save them in a special table but I have no idea how to find these keywords!

because the code runs every 5min so it use lots of server source and I want to have not heavy codes!

I myself have an old idea that split text by words and count them and get the top 5 words but almost always the keywords should be something like "a" or "the" etc

any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you need a list of stop words - a list of words that contain 'a', 'the', etc that you don't allow to be part of your list of keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download an English dictionary such as Webster's Unabridged Dictionary from the Gutenberg Project (http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29765/29765-8.txt) and parse it for pronouns and prepositions and use the result as a list of words to ignore in your count.

A quick and dirty parsing experiment based on the above provided the following list:

```
AMONGST         A               ABOON           AGAINST         AMID            
AT              ATAFTER         BATING          BEHITHER        BESIDE          
BESIDES         BETWIXT         DURANTE         DURING          EMFORTH         
FOREBY          FORENENST       FROM            HE              HERS            
HERSELF         HIMSELF         HIMSELVE        HIR             HIS             
HO              I               ICH             IDEM            IK              
INTO            INWITH          IT              ITSELF          MALGRE          
MYSELF          MYSELVEN        O'              OF              ONESELF         
ONTO            OURSELVES       OUTCEPT         OUTTAKE         PER             
REGARDING       RESPECTING      SENZA           SHE             SITH            
THAT            THEM            THEMSELVES      THESE           THILK           
THOSE           THRU            THURGH          THY             THYSELF         
UMBE            UNNEAR          UPON            UPTILL          US              
VERSUS          WE              WHATE'ER        WHATEVER        WHATSOEVER      
WHICH           WHO             WHOEVER         WHOM            WHOMSOEVER      
WHOSE           WHOSESOEVER     WHOSO           WHOSOEVER       WITHOUTEN       
YER             YMEL            YOU             YOURS           YOURSELF        
YOW
```

As mentioned, needs refinement...

Comment: NLTK is a better way of doing it though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Natural Language Toolkit ([NLTK](http://nltk.org/)), including the freely-available [book](http://nltk.org/book/). That will get you started, although this is a bit of an open-ended question.